# Python: KeyError: 'style_code' even when style_code is in my json data

Tags: json, python-3.x, tkinter

I might just need new eyes to look at this but im not sure why im yielding this error `KeyError: 'style_code'`

I know that style code is in my json data and i looked up why this error occurs and it said it was because it cannot find it in the list. Here is my code of the json data...

```
data1['task'].append({
                'profile': profiles_select.get(),
                'proxy pool': pool_combo.get(),
                'captcha': captcha,
                'task_id': num_id,
                'style_code': stylecode_entry.get(),
                'delay': int(delay_entry.get()),
                'size': size,
                'splash': splash,
                'browser': browser
            })
            num_id = num_id + 1
            with open('tasks_ys.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                json.dump(data1, outfile, indent=2)
```

As you can see 'style_code' is clearly stated in there. Here is my code which is giving me the error.

```
                with open('tasks_ys.txt', 'r') as json_file:
                    load_data = json.load(json_file)
                for task in load_data['task']:
                    style_c = load_data['style_code']
                    product_lbl = Label(ys_tasks_frame, text=style_c, bg='#1a2228', fg=fgcolor,
                                        font=("Candara", 12))
                    product_lbl.place(x=150, y=task_y)
                    id_lbl = Label(ys_tasks_frame, text=num_t, bg='#1a2228', fg=fgcolor, font=("Candara", 12))
                    id_lbl.place(x=25, y=task_y)
                    num_t = num_t + 1

                    task_y = task_y + 25
```

Can anyone help me and point out what is wrong about the code?

Comment: `style_c = load_data['style_code']` should be `style_c = task['style_code']`.

Comment: @acw1668 omg i knew it was another stupid error! Thank you!